# IAM policy not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an IAM policy which is as :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["ec2:Describe*"],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:127890:instance/i-31f"
    }
]
```

}

But this policy is not working for me. Kindly help

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish with the policy ?

Comment: I want a user to just view the instances and it should have the start stop permission on his instance only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to describe what you need to accomplish but for starters, you are missing a `ec2:DescribeInstances` on the first `Action` statement:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/id number"
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure you used the right accountid and the right instance id.

Comment: let me try. i want to view all the instances but i want to start and stop only specific instances

Comment: sry but i have edited this policy its still not working

Comment: Check my edit. You need `ec2:DescribeInstances`. Make sure you used the right accountid and the right instance id.

Comment: If i want to restrict a user to multiple instances than i just need to add `"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/id number"` multiple times ?